# File not found exception when build Unity app for Android

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to build a Unity app for Android and am getting the following error:

```
Building Library\Bee\artifacts\Android\AsyncPluginsFromLinker failed with output:
```

UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException: Burst compiler (1.8.4) failed running

stdout:
Error: Failed to find entry-points:
System.Exception: Error while hashing assembly C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Variations\mono\Managed\UnityEngine.dll ---> System.AggregateException:
One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.

The system cannot find the file specified.
---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.

The system cannot find the file specified.

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at System.Buffers.DefaultArrayPool`1.Rent(Int32 minimumLength)
at Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.Storage.StringCollection.AddString(String value)

....

....

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

To make sure it wasn't something within the app, I created a completely empty app and tried to build that. Same result.

Using Unity version 2022.3.1f1

I should add that I deleted a few programs on my computer recently. So maybe I deleted some dot net stuff I need.